# Jqwidget checkbox in grid cell is allways checked even if its value coming from Json is false

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3, javascript-framework

Jqwidget checkbox in grid cell is allways checked even if its value coming from Json is false inside asp .net mvc3 project.(At database side, I used bit and at server side I used bool type in model definition)

[image: Incoming Json]
[image: Resulting Grid]

The source part at client is:

```
var source = {
            datatype: "json",
            datafields: [{ name: 'KargoId' }, { name: 'Ad' }, { name: 'Soyad' }, { name: 'Urun' }, { name: 'Uygunluk' },
                         { name: 'YuklenmeTarihi', type: 'date' }, { name: 'Adet' }, { name: 'Fiyat'}],
            url: 'BindEditGrid'
        };
```

And column definition for checkbox column is:

```
{ text: 'Uygun', datafield: 'Uygunluk', columntype: 'checkbox', width: 67 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of the boolean columns should be set to 'boolean' in the datafields definition.